# Decoding the following APDU command both (request and response)

Tags: apdu

Request => 00 A4 00 00 02 7FF0 00

Response<= 00 00 00 00 7F F0 02 00 00 00 00 00 13 33 01 15

Answer (score 0):

```
  TAG_OPERATION (10017), Length: 4, Data: 02 00 00 00 
  TAG_OBJECT_ID (10018), Length: 27, Data: 
    TAG_TOP (65001001), Length: 21, Data: 
      TAG_ELEMENT (65001002), Length: 15, Data: 
        TAG_ARRAY (1001b), Length: 10, Data: 
          TAG_SYSCONFIG (1001e), Length: 5, Data: 
            TAG_GENERAL_CONFIG (102a0), Length: 0, Data: 
  TAG_CONSTRAINT (10019), Length: 24, Data: 
    TAG_DATA (1001a), Length: 19, Data: 
      TAG_GENERAL_CONFIG (102a0), Length: 14, Data: 
        TAG_BOOLEAN (10072), Length: 9, Data: 
          TAG_STATS_LOGGING (102a6), Length: 4, Data: 00 00 00 00     ""


10/13/2015 06:04:09.196: NAVICIMOM

hr = 0x0
time to complete: 62 msec

<--- Last TLD Request Repeated --->


10/13/2015 06:25:04.259: NAVICIMOM
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to GSM11.11 specification.
Request:

```
00 CLASS = USIM
    A4 = SELECT Command
        00 00 = P1 P2 
               02 = Length
                   7FF0 = File ID
```

Response also defined in GSM11.11 Section 9.2.1. basically its saying the id is 7FF0. 02 means its a DF (Folder). something seams wrong with the "13" as this should be the length of the data to follow.
the 01 should mean this directory has 1 sub-directory and the 15 should mean it has 0x15 files within it.